# Split Table View array into label and subtitle

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

New to Xcode and I was looking through some apple documentories and it was showing how I could set the text and subtitle. My problem with the guides is how to implement them.

This is how my array currently is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Initialize the array.
    listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //Add items
    [listOfItems addObject:@"Iceland"];
    [listOfItems addObject:@"Greenland"];
    [listOfItems addObject:@"Switzerland"];
    [listOfItems addObject:@"Norway"];
    [listOfItems addObject:@"New Zealand"];
    [listOfItems addObject:@"Greece"];
    [listOfItems addObject:@"Rome"];
    [listOfItems addObject:@"Ireland"];

}
```

and this is how it returns the data:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Set up the cell...
    NSString *cellValue = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

    return cell;
}
```

This is just with the title though and I would like to put in a subtitle. 
What code would I insert to implement the subtitle?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the subtitle for your cell, use the `detailtextLabel` property:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"My Subtitle";
```

You should also make sure your cell's style is set to `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` if you want the subtitle to appear the normal way (left aligned, below the main text label, and in slightly smaller gray font)

Comment: How would I set the cell's style?

Comment: Set the style on your table's prototype cell in your app's storyboard. (Highlight the cell, go to the Attributes Inspector in the right column, and look for "Style").  Or in the code you could use the the initializer method `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` when creating the cell.